# Do the sensor fusion algorithms of Core Motion take advantage of the Kalman filter?

Tags: iphone, kalman-filter, core-motion

Do the sensor fusion algorithms of Core Motion take advantage of the Kalman filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update on June 22, 2016**

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionmanager) provided by Apple,

> The processed device-motion data provided by Core Motion’s sensor
>   fusion algorithms gives the device’s attitude, rotation rate,
>   calibrated magnetic fields, the direction of gravity, and the
>   acceleration the user is imparting to the device.

That is, some sort of sensor fusion algorithm has been provided by now. I cannot tell from this piece of information whether that sensor fusion algorithm is the Kalman filter, or something equally good.

---

<sub>(Answer back from 2011.)</sub>

No, according to [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/53301-gyro-drift.html).

**Update on Aug 20, 2011**

It is not clear from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW26) (note: this linked pages has disappeared by June 22, 2016) what is actually provided. It does not seem to be a Kalman filter implementation.

[According to Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937867/detect-when-an-iphone-has-been-bumped/6939355#6939355) (who sent me the above link) his own Kalman filter provides better results.

Comment: Soory, I don't see the part where it says: Does not use Kalman.