# How to detect jump with Core Motion?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I want to make jump rope counter, but I don't know how to detect jump and I did't find any solution for it. Please, help!

```
final class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {
    private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    private var jumpCounter = 0

    func jump() {
        let xAxis = motionManager.deviceMotion!.userAcceleration.x
        let yAxis = motionManager.deviceMotion!.userAcceleration.y
        let zAxis = motionManager.deviceMotion!.userAcceleration.z
        let xGravity = motionManager.deviceMotion!.gravity.x
        let yGravity = motionManager.deviceMotion!.gravity.y
        let zGravity = motionManager.deviceMotion!.gravity.z
        // I don't know how to detect a jump here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = self.updateDataInterval
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { (_, _) in
            self.jump()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when an iphone has been bumped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937867/detect-when-an-iphone-has-been-bumped)